# Is there any significant political movement in England to get rid of Monarchy?

Tags: united-kingdom, constitutional-monarchy

I know that there are/were significant political movements to get rid of the Queen's rule in some former colonies and Commonwealth states (from USA in 1776 to 1980/90s in Australia - see [Republic Advisory Committee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_Advisory_Committee)).

Is there a non-fringe political movement in England itself with the main aim of doing away with the Monarchy?

Non-fringe being many members, and/or official representation in government.

The anti-monarchy must be the main (or one of the main) goals - I would guess that Communists have that as one of the goals but it's not their main one most likely.

Comment: When you say England, do you really mean the UK?

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff - most people have [no clue](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNu8XDBSn10) about the differences :)

Comment: @DVK: I know. I'm trying to educate them all... :-(

Comment: It's worth noting that the Leader of [Her Majesty's most loyal] Opposition, Jeremy Corbyn (Labour), is for the abolition of the monarchy; but although this is well known, he has yet to make any official comment whist leader of the Labour Party, nor is it Labour Party policy.

Answer (score 7):

The only political party with official representation in government that supports and even calls for the removal of monarchy is the [Green Party of England and Wales](http://www.greenparty.org.uk/). A summary of their positions on the monarchy can be found in the party's [2005 General Election manifesto](http://greenparty.org.uk/files/manifesto/Manifesto%2005.pdf):

> **Elected House of Lords**
>
> The House of Lords will be reformed to become a fully elected body chosen by 
>   proportional representation.
>
> **Constitutional reform**
>
> A Constitutional Commission will be set up to draft a written constitution. The 
>   Church of England should be disestablished and the monarchy should no longer 
>   have formal legislative, executive or judicial roles.

The party, according to its [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Party_of_England_and_Wales), currently holds:

- 1 seat in the House of Commons
- 2 seats in the London Assembly
- 141 local government seats

Furthermore, a fairly well known political organization that campaigns for republicanism in the UK is the aptly named [Republic](http://www.republic.org.uk/) pressure group. Republic is a member of the [Alliance of European Republican Movements](http://www.aerm.org/), a movement to abolish monarchy in European countries with members from seven of the extant European monarchies.

That said, none of the three major parties in the UK (the Conservative Party, the Labour Party and the Liberal Democrats) advocates for the abolition of monarchy. Also, in 2012 the monarchy enjoyed record support [according to polls](http://www.guardian.co.uk/uk/2012/may/24/queen-diamond-jubilee-record-support), with 69% of respondents saying that Britain would be worse off without the monarchy.

Comment: Judging from the words quoted, I am not convinced that the Green party wants to utterly abolish the monarchy. *"The monarchy should no longer have formal legislative, executive or judicial roles"* seems to allow for the monarchy to continue in other roles - or even to assume that it will. For instance it could continue in a purely ceremonial role, and the disestablished Church of England could continue to have the monarch as head of that church if it wanted to. Does the Green party say more elsewhere about exactly what its manifesto position on the monarchy would mean in practice?

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that the Leader of [Her Majesty's most loyal] Opposition, Jeremy Corbyn, is for the abolition of the monarchy; but although this is well known, he has yet to make any official comment whist leader of the Labour Party, nor is it Labour Party policy.

There are also other republican MPs, such as Jim McGovern, Stephen Pound, and Ian Davidson (all Labour), among others. The vast maority of these MPs that are agaisnt the idea of the monarchy are Labour, one or two are Scottish Nationalists, and there are also Green, Liberal Democrat, and Plaid Cymru current and former MPs who are known republicans. There are no known Conservative republican MPs.